# How ^ and $ works in Java Regular Expression

Tags: java, regex

I want to learn the working of `^` and `$` symbols in Java Regular Expression.

`$` for end. Ok fine.

**1: What is the meaning of `^` symbol?**

Somewhere I read `^` used to start the string, but I read from the [Oracle Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/char_classes.html) that `^` used for abstraction as `[^abc]` means anything except `abc`.

**2: How `^` and `$` works.**

when I write `$` at the end then it gives me the ending match. 7123456789`7123456780`

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[789][0-9]{9}$");
Matcher m = p.matcher("71234567897123456780");
while(m.find()){
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

**Output:** 7123456780

when I write `^` at the start then it gives me the starting match. `7123456789`7123456780

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[789][0-9]{9}$");
Matcher m = p.matcher("71234567897123456780");
while(m.find()){
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

**Output:** 7123456789

and when I use `^` and `$` same time then it gives me no output as I read from  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21974304/and-in-java-regular-expression)  that it reads complete line that's why no match because number increases than 10.

I know the meaning of [789], [0-9], {9} and also know that the string matches two time. first time 7123456789 and second time 7123456780. But I want to learn the working of `^` and `$` symbol.

There is similar question with less information than I required.
[^ and $ in Java regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21974304/and-in-java-regular-expression)

Comment: 1. Those are both true.

Comment: @SLaks when meaning changes? mean where `^` will work as abstraction or starting of string?

Comment: The caret (`^`) is interpreted differently depending if it's enclosed in square brackets (`[` and `]`). If they are, then it denotes an exclusion (anything except a, b or c). If not, then it denotes the beginning of the string.

Comment: @Nothing - `^` only means "not" when it's inside square brackets.

Comment: @ChrisForrence what's about the remaining part of question?

Comment: Note that `$` is also interpreted differently if it is inside square brackets: then it's a literal `$`.

Comment: @Nothing, are you asking about what happens when both are used in the expression (`^[789][0-9]{19}$`)?

Comment: when you use `^` and `$` at same time, it will give **no match** because your 10th character is not `end of string` (or `$`). In this case, it would only match if your subject string is, for eg. `712345678` ([see here](https://regex101.com/r/sS5vgP/1))

Comment: @ChrisForrence yes both and separately too.

Comment: I mean, in the question, you seem to already understand what they mean. `^` anchors the regular expression to the start of the line, `$` anchors it to the end of the line, so using both anchors the expression to encompass the entire string.

Comment: @ChrisForrence I mean when I add `^` then why I get just starting match, why not 2 time? `7123456789` and `7123456780` and when I use `$` then why it just print the ending match? does `^` mean start the string and end once the first match found? and `$` mean get the last match?